# How does C++ placement delete work internally (C++ runtime)? How to overcome its limitation?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator, placement-new

C++ is asymmetric of placement new and placement delete. We are allowed to overload placement new in almost arbitrary ways. However, the placement delete functions are *only* called from placement new expressions. In particular, they are called if the constructor of the object throws an exception. There's no way to invoke placement delete for application code at all.

I have following confusions and questions to be clarified:

1) Why can't C++ compiler simply reject a placement new method signature if there's no placement delete counterpart defined? Doing that could help kill the possibilities of memory leak in that context.

2) If I have multiple memory pools (managed by application code) and I want different placement new to allocate memory from different pools, there's simply no way to support that due to the the fact that there's no way to know which memory pool the pointer came from in operator delete? (operator delete only has void* info). Is there any way I can accomplish this in C++?

```
struct Node {
    void* operator new(size_t size, Strategy s) {
        // Depend on different strategy, allocate memory
        // from different Memory pool
    }

    void operator delete(void* memory, Strategy s) {
        // Return the memory to different Memory pool
        // depends on the Strategy
        // However this delete will only be invoked by
        // c++ runtime if Node constructor throws.
    }

    void operator delete(void* memory, size_t s) {
        // This delete doesn't have any clue about the
        // the strategy. Hence, it can't decide which
        // Memory pool to return to.
    }
}
```

3) In the context of placement new, C++ runtime will invoke placement delete with same argument. How does C++ runtime accomplish this?

Comment: Can you use a "smart pointer"?

Comment: Your comment is not remotely relevant.

Comment: If you're doing `T* p = new (memory) T();`, shouldn't you be doing `p->~T();`?  What is "placement `delete`"?

Comment: You don't need placement new: it just calls the destructor, and you can just do that directly.  Therefore, there's no reason to call it.  Wait, are you _overriding_ placement new behavior?  Is that even allowed? It's definitely not a good idea...

Comment: @jamesdlin: I think he's overriding placement new to have additional behavior, and trying to override placement delete to clean up this additional behavior.  But the placement delete form is only called from placement new, and is otherwise uncallable. I've never heard of this arising before, because I've never heard of anyone overriding placement new before.

Comment: @MooingDuck The allocation functions that are invoked by `new` are replacable , so the user can control allocation (and/or debug it)

Comment: @M.M: Yes, I refer to placement allocation functions and placement deallocation functions.

Comment: The design of operator new/delete is somewhat broken in C++. The fact that we cannot pass parameters to `delete` is a bad thing in my opinion. The only solution I know is to completely avoid using operator new/delete (except placement new), and roll your own system.

Comment: @geza How do we avoid operator new if we want to control the memory mangement? If we new an object, compiler will inevitably invoke operator new for us. Do you meant to say not overload operator new/delete (except using the default placement new ?)

Comment: @OliverYoung: The general idea is, that instead of `Foo *f = new(myAllocator) Foo(a, b, c);`, use `Foo *f = myAllocator->allocate<Foo>(a, b, c);`, and instead of `delete`, use `myAllocator->free(f);`.

Comment: @geza I see. I assume myAllocator->allocate<Foo> and myAllocator->free<Foo> will invoke constructor and destructor internally?

Comment: @OliverYoung: Yes. The constructor is called by placement new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes the question refers to [user-defined placement allocation functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new):

```
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, user-defined-args... );
void* operator new[]( std::size_t count, user-defined-args... );
```

and [user-defined placement deallocation functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete):

```
void operator delete  ( void* ptr, args... );
void operator delete[]( void* ptr, args... );
```

The behaviour of these functions is:

- `operator new`:  If defined, called by the custom single-object placement new expression with the matching signature. If a class-specific version is defined, it is called in preference to this. If neither is provided by the user, the placement new expression is ill-formed.
- `operator new[]`: Ditto but for array form.
- `operator delete`: If defined, called by the custom single-object placement new expression with the matching signature if the object's constructor throws an exception. If a class-specific version is defined, it is called in preference to this. If neither is provided by the user, no deallocation function is called.
- `operator delete[]`: Ditto but for array form.

---

To answer your questions:

1. Don't pay for what you don't use.  There might be a setup where no deallocation function is required.
2. You'll have to include a mechanism whereby the value of the `void *` pointer being deleted can be used to determine which memory pool it is in.  This must be possible because your different pools can't return the same value simultaneously. A naive method might be to have each pool manage a non-overlapping address range and test the pointer against each pool's address range.  Or perhaps you could store metadata in memory before the pointed-to location, e.g. the `new` version would allocate N+16 bytes, store metadata in the first 16, and return to the user a pointer to the 16th byte of the block).  Or you could keep a data structure associating each active pointer with metadata.
3. Evaluation of the new-expression for allocating an object of class type will go something like:

   - Call `operator new`, passing the arguments
   - Assuming that succeeds, call class constructor (if it's a class type being allocated).
   - If the class constructor throws, and matching `operator delete` exists, call that function, passing the arguments.
   - Now evaluation of the new-expression is finished, and control returns to either the code that contained the new-expression, or into the exception handling mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply.
1) Could you point me to a practical example where no deallocation function is not required? Isn't it much safer if compiler could error out at compile time to prevent the potential memory leak?

2) Storing metadata is more practical which is employed by lots of project. However, this relies on an assumption that all different memory pools are managed by the same management library. This may not be the case right. Let's say I have two third party memory management libraries A and B. Pass an memory address allocated by B to library A may corrupt the memory.

Comment: 3) I understand the mechanics.  But I am trying to figure out how does C++ accomplish the third point: 

"If the class constructor throws, and matching operator delete exists, call that function, passing the arguments."

How does it test if matching operator delete exists? I guess C++ compiler test this at compile time? (I can't think of anyway to test this at runtime). If that's the case, it goes back to my question one. I think it may be better to error out at compile time if a matching operator delete does not exist...

Comment: @OliverYoung (1) some task might only ever allocate and never exit, or run on an OS that deallocates the process memory on exit. (2) you could include the library ID in your metadata, (3) it's up to the compiler/linker to know if these functions exist or not. C++ doesn't hold your hand, and this is an advanced topic, if you're writing a memory allocator then you should be capable of providing matching signatures and testing your code.

Comment: (1) For such usage, C++ design could ask user to provide an no-op operator delete. In fact, this is what C++ standard placement delete does, isn't it? (void* operator delete(void*, void*) ). And error out at compile time if no matching operator delete exists.

Comment: I am trying to understand the design rationale behind this. 

On one hand, C++ ask user to always invoke the default operator delete when no exception is thrown, with the assumption that user should rely on metadata stored near the memory location to figure out what to do. 

On the other hand, C++ ask user to provide overloaded operator delete to prevent memory leak when exception is thrown.

Wouldn't it be nice if C++ could unify the deallocation mechanism?

Comment: @OliverYoung `operator delete(void*, void*)`  (item 9 in cppreference) always exists, the compiler provides one and the user can optionally replace it. This is different to user-defined placement (de-)allocation where none is provided since you make up the signature you want for the allocation version.   I don't see what you mean by "unify the deallocation mechanism".  If you're proposing that the compiler should "remember" what arguments were provided to `new` for every single pointer, that would be a huge performance penalty imposed on users who do not require that.

Comment: (1) I am aware that operator delete(void*, void*) always exists. I think that's C++ way to handle special case (i.e. "no-op") where normal operator delete can't handle. As you pointed out, there may be task doesn't need deallocation. In that case, C++ could require users to provide a similar user-defined "no-op" operator delete. C++ could choose to reject/error out when operator delete counterpart doesn't exist instead of silently memory leak when exception is thrown. I feel that's a much safer approach.

Comment: (2) By unify, I mean C++ could choose one of following two deallocation policy consistently no matter exception is thrown or not. (a) Overload their deallocation logic based on metadata stored near memory address. or (b) Overloaded deallocation logic based on overload of operator delete. 

Ask user to relying on policy (a) when no exception is throw from constructor and at the same time, C++ run-time use policy (b) when exception is thrown. This seems a bit un-intuitive to me.

Comment: For (a) the choice is up to the user. You don't have to use metadata stored near the address.  If the implementation mandated something like that it would be a penalty to those who don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Having looked it up: you're supposed to provide a Node::destroy that gets rid of the node and returns it to your local heap.

If these were generic `new` with for `void*` we would have the following destroy:

```
template<class T> void destroy (Strategy s, T* ptr)
{
    ptr->~T();
    // return to custom heap
 }
```

You could use fancy tricks to get rid of strategy, like checking what heap ptr is in, or storing it at a negative offset in `new`.

Useless historical answer:

It's been a long time, but I remember the syntax being

```
delete (strategy) pointer;
```

This appears to be vendor specific nonsense from BC4.5.

Comment: It's not possible to restrict the user from writing `delete ptr;` instead of calling `destroy` so perhaps the thing to do is to implement the intended behaviour for `delete ptr;` with the so-called "fancy tricks" and offer this option as an optimization when the strategy is known by the caller.

Comment: @M.M: I only ever did `new (size_t, int)` with no type so that was unavailable to me. Calling `delete` outright was an accident waiting to happen.